# Mapping Column Values Of One CSV To The Header Values Of Another CSV And Writing A New CSV File

Tags: php, arrays, file, csv, mapping

I am trying to build (program) an interface with PHP that takes 1 CSV file (csv1) and uses the headers from that CSV file to map the columns of another CSV file (csv2). I was able to get the mapping into an array with the following:

```
//csv1
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', file('csv1.csv'));

//just get the first line of the csv1's values
$csv1Headers = array_shift($data);

//csv2
$data2 = array_map('str_getcsv', file('csv2.csv'));

//get csv2's header values
$csv2Headers = array_shift($data2);

//set variables based on csv2's headers
$csv2header1 = array_search("header1", $csv2Headers);
$csv2header2 = array_search("header2", $csv2Headers);
$csv2header3 = array_search("header3", $csv2Headers);
$csv2header4 = array_search("header4", $csv2Headers);


//create main array
$mappedArray = array();

//create individual arrays based on csv1's header values 
foreach($csv1Headers as $header) {
    $mappedArray[$header] = array();
}

//Set the 
foreach ($data2 as $row) {
    if($row[$csv2header1]) { $mappedArray['csv1header1'][] .= $row[$csv2header1]; } else { $mappedArray['csv1header1'][] .= ''; }
    if($row[$csv2header2]) { $mappedArray['csv1header2'][] .= $row[$csv2header2]; } else { $mappedArray['csv1header2'][] .= ''; }
    if($row[$csv2header3]) { $mappedArray['csv1header3'][] .= $row[$csv2header3]; } else { $mappedArray['csv1header3'][] .= ''; }
    if($row[$csv2header4]) { $mappedArray['csv1header4'][] .= $row[$csv2header4]; } else { $mappedArray['csv1header4'][] .= ''; }
}
```

if I run `print_r($mappedArray)` I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [csv1Header1] => Array
        (
            [0] => csv2DataMappedToHeader1
            [1] => csv2DataMappedToHeader1
            [2] => csv2DataMappedToHeader1

        )

    [csv1Header2] => Array
        (
            [0] => csv2DataMappedToHeader2
            [1] => csv2DataMappedToHeader2
            [2] => csv2DataMappedToHeader2

        )

    [csv1Header3] => Array
        (
            [0] => csv2DataMappedToHeader3
            [1] => csv2DataMappedToHeader3
            [2] => csv2DataMappedToHeader3

        )

    [csv1Header4] => Array
        (
            [0] => csv2DataMappedToHeader4
            [1] => csv2DataMappedToHeader4
            [2] => csv2DataMappedToHeader4
        )
    )
```

Now what I want to know is how do I write a new CSV file that outputs:

```
"csv1Header1", "csv1Header2", "csv1Header3", "csv1Header4"
"csv2DataMappedToHeader1","csv2DataMappedToHeader2","csv2DataMappedToHeader3","csv2DataMappedToHeader4"
"csv2DataMappedToHeader1","csv2DataMappedToHeader2","csv2DataMappedToHeader3","csv2DataMappedToHeader4"
"csv2DataMappedToHeader1","csv2DataMappedToHeader2","csv2DataMappedToHeader3","csv2DataMappedToHeader4"
```

I can't figure out how to do that... any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fputcsv` to write your output to a file:

```
$array = ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'date');
$fh = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fh, $array);
```

`output.csv`:

> `"apple","banana","carrot","date"`

However, you might find that the data structure you've used isn't all that conducive to printing, since it's arranged in columns, rather than rows.

As a general hint, whenever you find yourself repeating an operation more than twice, it's worth abstracting the operation to create a more general version of it. For example, this code:

```
//set variables based on csv2's headers
$csv2header1 = array_search("header1", $csv2Headers);
$csv2header2 = array_search("header2", $csv2Headers);
$csv2header3 = array_search("header3", $csv2Headers);
$csv2header4 = array_search("header4", $csv2Headers);
```

could be refactored; rather than having a set of variables with similar names, use a `for` loop and put the data in an array:

```
$csv2hdr = array();
for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {
    # searches for "header1", "header2", etc.
    # stores them in $csv2hdr[1], $csv2hdr[2], etc.
    $csv2hdr[$i] = array_search("header$i", $csv2Headers);
}
```

It also looks like you're using the string append operator (`.=`) when you should be using the `=` operator here:

```
$mappedArray['csv1header1'][] .= $row[$csv2header1];
```

Hope that helps!